# Is Dr. House of Dutch descent?

Tags: character, house

In the series, is it ever mentioned that Gregory House is of Dutch descent? If so, when is it explained or suggested?

The reason for asking is that I found him listed on [Wikipedia's 'Category:Fictional American people of Dutch descent' list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fictional_American_people_of_Dutch_descent).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the episode "one day, one room" (season 3 episode 12) he tells a story to a rape victim about his Dutch grandmother who he called Oma, which is actually the Dutch word for grandmother.

In the end, part of that story (about mistreatment) turns out to be about his father, not his grandmother, so it's a bit vague if the rest about his grandmother was truthful. But it is reasonable to assume that part wasn't a lie as her origins had no real importance to the story, so why lie about it.

Comment: That means that Dr. House's ancestry is at least 25 percent Dutch, with the other 75 percent undetermined unless someone remembers other information from other episodes.

Comment: I wonder if they picked Dutch because "House" sounds plausibly like a transliterated Dutch name.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim If you mean based on the sound of the dutch word, then I doubt it, there is no word in dutch that sounds similar. The Dutch translation is spelled "Huis" and pronounced very differently (/ɦœy̯s/), I don't actually think English has such a sound. You might be thinking of the German 'Haus', which is closer to English.

Comment: @KillianDS Sorry, I meant "to an English speaker, 'House' sounds like it could be a Dutch word" so maybe they picked it out of thin air, not necessarily that it actually was haha.